# how to load classes and PHPMailer in the same file

Tags: php

I would like to create Trigger which send emails 
I tried to to add :

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'autoload.php';


spl_autoload_register(function ($class_name) {

    $file_name = $class_name . '.php';

    if( file_exists( $file_name ) ) {

        require $file_name;

    }
});

.......

new TriggerDocs();


class TriggerDocs{

$mail = new PHPMailer(true); // not working

}
```

> Fatal error: Class 'PHPMailer' not found in path/Trigger.php

Comment: Are you sure the spl_autoload_register works correctly ? looks like it does not

Comment: is the PHPMailer file exist in the mention path  ?

Comment: Yes, it works, the error displayed from the Trigger ;)

Comment: I created a file to send email using 
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
require 'autoload.php';

it's work 
I also created another file to  test the autoload function , its works too

but when i mix them , i have the error

Comment: If ```path/Trigger.php``` is included into another file, then try to define an absolute path for ```autoload.php```

Answer (score 0):

use doesn't include anything. It just imports the specified namespace (or class) to the current scope .